# Struct in a XMacro

Tags: c, struct, x-macros

I am trying to assign a value to a struct from the XMacro table.

Is there any other way to assign the "offset" to this value of the struct?

```
typedef enum Time_Unit_Tag
{
    NO_UNIT,
    HOUR,
    MINUTES,
    SECONDS,
    TOTAL_UNITS
} Time_Unit_T;

enum
{
    OFFSET_HOUR = 0,
    OFFSET_MIN  = 2,
    OFFSET_SEC  = 4
};

#define CHANGE_TIME \
TIME(HOUR,    "HOUR"   ,  OFFSET_HOUR)\
TIME(MINUTES, "MINUTES",  OFFSET_MIN )\
TIME(SECONDS, "SECONDS",  OFFSET_SEC )\

#undef TIME
#define TIME(unit, desc, offset)\
if(count == unit)\
{\
    P(desc)\
    format_clock.offset = offset;\
}\
```

Comment: Use `offestof` from `<stddef.h>`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need an X macro at all?

Comment: I´m trying to assign to a structure the value obtained from the marco table

Comment: There is no need for `\`` in code blocks. That's just for inline code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a structure, actually an array for the 3 items

```
struct {
    Time_Unit_T unit;
    char *desc;
    int offset;  // could also use enum{}, but the one above has no tag
} mystruct[3]
```

and initialize it

```
= {
#define TIME(u, d, o)  { u, d, o },
CHANGE_TIME
};
```

With the x-macro, you define a new inner macro in the right format. Here `{ u, d, o },` the format for an initializer.